# Is it bad to have "number" as object keys?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just searched through SO and it looks like everybody agrees with the idea that JavaScript and TypeScript are not supporting using numbers as keys in an object directly. But somehow my fellow developer has used some objects with numeric keys in our Angular project which are working just fine as other objects. This is what they look like.

```json
{
   1: 1,
   2: 0,
   3: 2
}
```

And calling the value in a form like `obj[2]` does not have a problem at the moment. Just wondering if it is the right way to do it, and how well this usage is supported?

Comment: it is standard by arrays, which are exotic objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its fine, as in - its *legal*, as its how arrays work, though one thing to watch out for is that arrays will ensure the key is incremental, starting at 0, whereas a numerical key in an object will not, and WILL be misleading for other developers when they cant understand why obj[1] doesnt always live beside obj[2] etc, and by that I mean the use of within loops etc and simply incrementing the index by one each time.  So, personally i wouldnt recommend it due to it looking like an array, but it not actually being an array...

Side - If you are trying to mimic an array, but want an index starting at 1, just use an array as normal and have your code just handle the offset each time.  Arrays come with many functions, like `length`, `sort`, `find` etc that an object will not

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Currently, those numbers stand for the id of certain other objects, so the object is used as "an object with keys that are exactly the same as those ids" rather than as an array in my case. Still, perhaps I should ask them to change those keys back to strings.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript keys in object are string type and if you have `obj[1]` it will automatically turn into `obj['1']` but not the same in `Map`

```js
const obj = {}

obj[1] = 'one';

console.log(obj[1]);
// output: "one"
console.log(obj['1']);
// output: "one"

obj['1'] = 'one string';

console.log(obj[1]);
// output: "one string"
console.log(obj['1']);
// output: "one string"

const map = new Map();
map.set(1, 'one');
map.set('1', 'one string');

console.log(map.get(1));
// output: "one"
console.log(map.get('1'));
// output: "one string"
```